# WebSphere: can I reload transaction settings without restarting jvm?

Tags: websphere, settings, reload

is it possible to reload transaction timeout settings without restarting JVM ?

Comment: Below is a link on how to change transaction timeout with scripting. AdminControl MBean, used to configure transaction service, generally manages 'live' stuff, so it may worth trying. http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Ftxml_transaction.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on @kurtcebe's answer. below commands will not reload settings but will apply settings on the runtime

```
set ts [$AdminControl completeObjectName cell=mycell,node=mynode,
process=server1,type=TransactionService,*]

$AdminControl setAttributes $ts {{clientInactivityTimeout 30} 
{totalTranLifetimeTimeout 180}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that this can be done. This affects every single application that runs on a JVM so I strongly believe this will not work without restarting the JVM.  kurtcebe's suggestion is definitely a way to test and make some observation(s).